# Run test cases using docker in scala

Tags: scala, docker, sbt

## This Dockerfile has two required ARGs to determine which base image

## to use for the JDK and which sbt version to install.

I am trying to run the test cases using docker file. The docker file is:

```
ARG OPENJDK_TAG=8u232
FROM openjdk:${OPENJDK_TAG}

ARG SBT_VERSION=1.2.7

RUN \
  curl -L -o sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian/sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb && \
  dpkg -i sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb && \
  rm sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb && \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install sbt && \
  sbt sbtVersion

WORKDIR /current

RUN sbt clean test

ENTRYPOINT sbt "~reStart --url ${URL}"
```

It starts my container but it does not execute the test cases. Is there any way i can run the test cases using sbt clean test using this docker file.

Comment: Your Dockerfile doesn't `COPY` your application code in, so I'd expect the `RUN sbt ...` line to fail for a missing `build.sbt` file.  Why run this during the Docker image build phase, instead of running `sbt test` from the host prior to building the image?

Answer (score 2):

You are telling sbt to run test using `RUN`, which is executed on when you build image. At this point what is inside image has no access to what is outside, sbt sees only empty project.

`test` should happen, similarly to `reStart`, the moment you `start` your docker image, because at this point you can mount volume to sbt project root, which the sbt inside container would use to build the project (stored outside the container). Personally I would suggest something like

```
ENTRYPOINT sbt
CMD ["clean", "test", "~reStart --url ${URL}"]
```

which would allow running docker image with different arguments

```
docker start sbt-image // run sbt clean test "~reStart --url ${URL}"
docker start sbt-image shell // run sbt shell
docker start sbt-image clean test // run sbt clean test
```

or if you really want this `clean` `test`  to be run every time you start container

```
ENTRYPOINT sbt clean test
CMD ["~reStart --url ${URL}"]
```